# Python: How to connect to Azure cloud storage using shared access key?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In .net I should be able to connect to the azure storage using SAS like this:

```
var someTable = new CloudTable("https://account-name.table.core.windows.net/table-name?sv={key}");
```

How can I do it in python? I could not find a CloudTable class in azure.storage.table (from azure sdk for python: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python)

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
import os
import json
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='[account-name]', sas_token='[sas-token]')
list = table_service.query_entities('[table-name]', top=100)
```

Replace `[account-name]`, `[sas-token]` and `[table-name]` with actual values.

**Also please do not include `?` from the SAS token for the `[sas-token]` field.**

Source: See the documentation here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py.

Comment: I'm still getting this error:
Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

My SAS token is something like this:
2015-01-01&tn=blah&sig=xxxxgxxxxxyyyyxxxxxkqdyyMY%2BexxxxxxxxRch%2B8%3D&se=2016-04-19T21%3A59%3A32Z&sp=r

Comment: There's something wrong with your SAS token. There should be an `sv=` in front of `2015-01-01`. So it should be like `sv=2015-01-01&tn=blah&sig=xxxxgxxxxxyyyyxxxxxkqdyyMY%2BexxxxxxxxRch%2B8%3D&se=2016-‌​04-19T21%3A59%3A32Z&sp=r` and there should be a `tn` parameter as well for table name. How are you creating your SAS token?